# CRUD button not working after said CRUD was inserted in a TopComponent

Tags: java, mysql, swing, button, crud

I hope the title wasn't too ambiguous, so here goes:

I have created a MySQL database in which I have stored two table: one containing input data, and the other containing the output data.

Afterwards I have written a program that connects to this specific database, extracts the data from the input table, it parses it, and then it stores it in the output table.

Then, I have created two Master/Detail Forms(SWING GUI Forms) each corresponding to one table. 
To the input data form I have attached a button simply labelled "Calculate", and put the above mentioned to-do code in it. So far, it is working good - the button does the job I created it to do.

The next step is this: using one topcomponent to display these modules side-by-side in one window, one stand-alone program. 
Finally, the problem is this: after inserting both modules in the topcomponent the "Calculate" button simply does not work anymore.

I have used this guide, step-by-step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXQg_guFL2k

So it all comes down to this last button. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: here's a piece of code describing the process of putting the output data in the output table:

```
    try {
            Statement stmt;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseExample";

            Connection con =
               DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","pwd"); 

            stmt=con.createStatement();

            stmt.executeUpdate("GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,"+ 
            "CREATE,DROP ON databaseExample.* TO 'mysql'@'localhost' " +
            "IDENTIFIED BY 'drowssap';");
            PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("insert into outputTable(workerID, workTimes, machineID) values (?,?,?)");

                for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
                st.setShort (1, workID[i]);     
                st.setDouble(2, workTime[i]);
                st.setString(3, machine[v[i]]);
                st.executeUpdate();
            }
            con.close();
        } 

        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your approach.

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for the quick response! Edited as requested.

Comment: This appears to be a fragment of your working code; your [short, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should focus on the problem.

Comment: This is the problem, I honestly do not know where the problematic code is, simply put, the input crud is working, so is the output one, but when I add them to the topcomponent it's just shot. Ever met a problem like this before? Could be a persistence problem of some sort?

Comment: If it always fails, you might look for one reference shadowing another; if intermittent, look for EDT violations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moments ago I just managed to make it work:

I was looking through the CRUD's code properties in the adjacent "Properties" tab in NetBeans when this caught my eye:  under "code generation" there was a property called "Variable modifiers" which was set to "private". After setting it to "public" it worked like a charm.

Thank you for your time! :)